# Making markers clickable with content from Firebase in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project at the moment and I'm wondering if there is a way to make a marker clickable on a map and make it open a modal that contains specific user-imported information from fire-base. ATM I have it posting the location of the note to Fire-base and retrieving it, displaying it on a map.

I have made it clickable and made it display an info-window that displayed the same content on each-marker. I'm curious to how I would make each marker individual using data from fire-base (Sorry, I'm repeating myself). I'll attach the code I have below. I am using a markercluster javascript to display the notes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Marker Clusterer -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <!-- Meta and Title -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>geoNote</title>

    <!-- Style -->
    <style>
        header {
            position: fixed;
            top: -30px;
            height: 200px;
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            color: #1aaa8d;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 49px;
            margin-left: -8px;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            z-index: 2;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0%;
            padding: 0%;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
        }
        footer {
            margin-left: -8px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            z-index: 2;
        }

        /*making the navigation bar, styles*/
        hr {
            border: 3px solid #0f6654;
        }
        ul {
            margin-top: 95px;
            margin-left: -10px;
            padding: 0;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: #1aaa8d;
            position: fixed;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: auto;
            top: 75px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            padding: 40px 70px;
            font-size: 55px;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /*Modal Styles*/
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 3; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 200px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
        }
        #aboutModal h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            font-size: 70px;
        }
        #settingsModal h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            font-size: 70px;
        }
        #aboutModal p,
        #settingsModal p{
            font-family: "Century Gothic";
            font-size: 50px;
        }
        #aboutModal a {
            font-size: 60px;
            color: #0f6654;
        }

        /*Theme slider*/
        .switch {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 113px;
            height: 68px;
        }
        .switch input {display:none;}
        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: black;
            -webkit-transition: .2s;
            transition: .2s;
        }
        .slider:before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            height: 52px;
            width: 52px;
            left: 4px;
            bottom: 8px;
            background-color: #1aaa8d;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }
        input:checked + .slider {
            background-color: black;
        }
        input:focus + .slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }
        input:checked + .slider:before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(52px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(52px);
            transform: translateX(52px);
        }

        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 68px;
        }
        .slider.round:before {
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!--Header-->
<header>
    <h1>geoNote</h1>
</header>

<!-- Map display -->
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<div id="navigation" class="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="postNoteBTN"><a class="button">Post</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="aboutBTN"><a class="button">About</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="settingsBTN"><a class="button">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Post modal -->
<div id="postModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="noteForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="messageSubject">Subject</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="messageSubject" placeholder="Subject of the message">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="messageContent">Message</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="messageContent" placeholder="Message content">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- About modal -->
<div id="aboutModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>GEOnote - a mobile app that allows its users
            to share messages by posting them on a real-life map.
        </p>
        </br>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.uk', '_system');">Visit GEOnote for more!</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Settings modal -->
<div id="settingsModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Theme DAY/NIGHT</p>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Script -->
<script>
    //post Modal
    var postModal = document.getElementById('postModal');
    var btn = document.getElementById("postNoteBTN");
    btn.onclick = function () {
        postModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    //about Modal
    var aboutModal = document.getElementById('aboutModal');
    var aboutBtn = document.getElementById("aboutBTN");
    aboutBtn.onclick = function () {
        aboutModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    //settings Modal
    var settingsModal = document.getElementById('settingsModal');
    var settingsBtn = document.getElementById("settingsBTN");
    settingsBtn.onclick = function () {
        settingsModal.style.display = "block";
    }

    //Window click closes Modal
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == settingsModal) {
            settingsModal.style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (event.target == aboutModal) {
            aboutModal.style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (event.target == postModal) {
            postModal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Map and Firebase -->
<script>
    //Firebase initialization
    var config = {...
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var note = firebase.database().ref('note/');

    //Map initialization
    var map, infoWindow;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887},
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        //Geolocation initialization
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

        //Geolocation error handling
        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

        //Place note
        var notes = [];
        var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, notes)

        note.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
            var position = snapshot.val();
            console.log(position);
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

            var noteIcon = 'https://i.imgur.com/mwIEFMG.png';
            var note = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                icon: noteIcon
            });

            cluster.addMarker(note);
        })
    }

    //Submit to database
    var submitNote = function () {
        var subject = $("#messageSubject").val();
        var message = $("#messageContent").val();
        var lat = localStorage.latitude;
        var lon = localStorage.longitude;

        note.push({
            "subject": subject,
            "message": message,
            "latitude": lat,
            "longitude": lon
        });
    }

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#noteForm").submit(submitNote);
    });
</script>

<!-- Google map API -->
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBg6cbfR9X1bz_peeYvhHibQAsGhwN9V7w&callback=initMap">
</script>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div id="location" ></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: absolutely. I'm doing it here --> https://getaa.org (click map on top and type in san francisco to see a populated map then click a marker.

Comment: @RonRoyston Thank you man! if you don't mind, if it's okay I view the source to lean how you did this? cheers

Comment: Glad to help. Here you go: https://github.com/rhroyston/getaa.org